# Intersections of two lists

Tags: python, python-2.x

Given two python lists `a` and `b`. These lists may intersect (It is possible that lists intersect more than once). An example:

> ```
> a = [1,2,5,7,6,9,1,3,1,2,6,6,3,1,2,6,1,3]
> b = [3,1,2]
> ```

There are 4 intersections:

> ```
>   [1,2,5,7,6,9,1,3,1,2,6,6,3,1,2,6,1,3]
> [3,1,2]         [3,1,2]   [3,1,2]   [3,1,2]
> ```

For each intersection I can write equality: `u + a + v == w + b + t`

I need to write a function that returns lists `u, v, w, t`. For this example these lists are:

```
1. u = [3], v = []
   w = [],  t = [5, 7, 6, 9, 1, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3]

2. u = [],  v = []
   w = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 1], t = [6, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3]

3. u = [],  v = []
   w = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 1, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6], t = [6, 1, 3]

4. u = [], v = [1, 2]
   w = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 1, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1], t = []
```

The following is a function I implemented (there is precondition: `len(lhs) >= len(rhs)`):

```
def get_additions(lhs, rhs):
    results = []
    szl = len(lhs)
    szr = len(rhs)
    i = 1 - szr
    while i < szl:
        a = max(0, i)
        b = max(0, -i)
        c = min(i + szr, szl)
        d = min(szr, szl - i)

        if (lhs[a:c] == rhs[b:d]):
            u = rhs[0:b]
            v = rhs[d:szr]
            w = lhs[0:a]
            t = lhs[c:szl]
            results.append((u, v, w, t))
        i += 1
    return results
```

How to make it better?

Answer (score 2):

- at line `if (lhs[a:c] == rhs[b:d]):` parentheses are redundant
- you don't need to return whole list, you can return only iterator (remove `results` variable, change line `results.append((u, v, w, t))` into `yield u, v, w, t)`. After it you can always use this as list if needed (`list(get_additions(a, b))`) but usually you need only iterator.
- your variable `i` change from <`1 - szr` .. `szl`). You can use `for i in xrange(1 - szr, szl):` to do this
- at your description i can read about conditions `u + a + v == w + b + t` and `len(lhs) >= len(rhs)`. You can write it in your code as assert
- at your description variables `a, b` means something else than in your code. It's not good idea. Your also use various conventions of variable naming (e.g. `szr` as size of right list and `b` as begining index of right list). You should define variables in the same way.
- personally i often remove variables like `szr` because len() of list is quite fast. It's your choice (you get less local variables but more len() calls).
- you always cut `b[3:len(b)]` into `b[3:]` and `b[0:3]` into `b[:3]`

After these changes your code could looks like

```
def get_additions(a, b):
    assert len(a) >= len(b)
    for i in xrange(1 - len(b), len(a)):
        a_left = max(0, i)
        b_left = max(0, -i)
        a_right = min(i + len(b), len(a))
        b_right = min(len(b), len(a) - i)

        if a[a_left:a_right] == b[b_left:b_right]:
            u = b[:b_left]
            v = b[b_right:]
            w = a[:a_left]
            t = a[a_right:]
            assert u + a + v == w + b + t
            yield u, v, w, t


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 6, 9, 1, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3]
    b = [3, 1, 2]
    for u, v, w, t in get_additions(a, b):
        print "u = %s, v = %s\nw = %s, t = %s\n" % (u, v, w, t)
```

Comment: `assert len(a) > len(b)` seems wrong based on the OP's problem description.

Comment: Thx, add description one.